# How can I create a iphone View like App Store's product introducion View?

Tags: view, scroll, store

I want to create a view like the style of app introduction in app store.
some text and pic at the top,when i browse down, and some pictures can be moved horizonal,
and at the bottom, some other description text.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView is used for displaying images horizontally, not sure about the rest.