# Whats the approach to create a view similar to the one at apple app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I wanted to know how can we design the view controller such that.., the upper half of the screen remains fixed and the below part of the screen can be navigated through.. !! 
Should we use slipScreenController here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a iphone View like App Store's product introducion View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506008/how-can-i-create-a-iphone-view-like-app-stores-product-introducion-view)

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds nothing like the Appstore app but the Appstore app simply has one vertical UIScrollView and another horizontal UIScrollView inside that for images.

Comment: Ok.., Thanks for the response..,But WHat I want is when the user clicks on the second half of the screen.., Only the second half of the screen should change, the first half of the screens remains fixed. Depending on the control logic, I can then navigate to the next respective screen..

Comment: Simple quick&dirty method: Make IBOutlets for two UIViews that cover half the screen each and then do `addSubview:` on `viewDidLoad` when you load in two other view controllers. So maybe you will have something like this in `viewDidLoad`: `MyViewController *a = bla bla; MyViewController2 *b = bla bla; [topHalf addSubview: a.view]; [bottomHalf addSubview: b.view];`. If you need to "navigate" the bottom half then you probably want a UINavigationController as `b`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to browsing categories in AppStore then:
That is a tableView implemented in such way that it doesn't take the whole screen area. You need to create a UIViewController (not UITableViewController) and than add a tableView to the view (using Interface Builder or code). That way you can change the size and position of the tableView and use the remaining area of the view for something else, for example a UISegmentedControl above the tableView.

If you are reffering to reading description and images of single app then I think that UIScrollView is used for displaying images, not sure about the rest.

Comment: Ok.., Thanks for the response..,But WHat I want is when the user clicks on the second half of the screen.., Only the second half of the screen should change, the first half of the screens remains fixed. Depending on the control logic, I can then navigate to the next respective screen..